# Choose aggregation based on respective date field

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have metrics at the rep and client level:

```
select r.rep_month, c.client_month, 
count(distinct r.id) reps, count(distinct c.id) clients
from clients c
left join reps r on c.rep_id=r.id
```

This of course doesn't work because it gives all combinations of rep_month/client_month- and from a time series stand point- they should be calculated based on two different dates.

What I need is for reps to be calculated based on rep_month and clients to be calculated based on client_month, so there should just be one date in the output.

A generalized example is like so:

```
rep_date     client_date    reps    clients
3/1/18 0:00  8/1/17 0:00    14      24
3/1/18 0:00  2/1/17 0:00    4       6
3/1/18 0:00  12/1/17 0:00   9       12
3/1/18 0:00  1/1/18 0:00    14      16
3/1/18 0:00  10/1/17 0:00   11      11
3/1/18 0:00  12/1/16 0:00   4       7
3/1/18 0:00  1/1/17 0:00    1       1
3/1/18 0:00  4/1/17 0:00    4       4
3/1/18 0:00  3/1/17 0:00    12      14
3/1/18 0:00  11/1/17 0:00   5       7
3/1/18 0:00  5/1/17 0:00    4       5
3/1/18 0:00  11/1/16 0:00   1       1
3/1/18 0:00  2/1/18 0:00    5       5
3/1/18 0:00  8/1/16 0:00    2       2
3/1/18 0:00  9/1/17 0:00    16      20
3/1/18 0:00  (null)         49      0
```

This would be the expected output:

```
date    reps    clients
3/1/18  49      135
```

But please note that **there can be cases where rep_date and client_date are not null**, so combining the two into: `coalesce(client_date,rep_date)` won't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Sample data going *into* the query would really help.  Also your sample results don't match the query, because one has months and the other has dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select mon, sum(reps) as reps, sum(clients) as clients 
from ((select c.client_month as mon, count(*) as clients, 0 as reps
       from clients c
       group by c.client_month
      ) union all
      (select r.rep_month, 0 as clients, count(*) as reps
       from reps r
       group by r.rep_month
      ) 
     ) rc
group by mon
order by mon;
```

Notes:

- You can also do this with a `join`, but you have to deal with time periods that are missing from either table (i.e., you need `full outer join` and lots of `coalesce()`).
- I am assuming that the `id`s are unique in each table, so `count(*)` and `count(distinct id)` do the same thing.  The former is more efficient, because it does not incur overhead to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
   Select r.rep_month, c.client, r.reps from
     (select rep_month, count(distinct id) reps 
         from reps
         group by rep_month) r 
   left join  
     (select client_month, count(distinct id) clients 
         from clients 
         group by client_month) c
   on r.rep_month = c.client_month
```

It doesn't make sense that you can join on id, just join on month. Or, if there is a main table with the id in it, start with that table first. Plus, the clients table has to have all the months in it.  If there are always reps every month, put that table first then left join.